# How do i know when the objectsList have all the objects after the nested method loop finished?

Tags: unity, c#

For example let's say the depthLevel  value is 2 and then in objectsList there is 76 items.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectList : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public int depthLevel = 0;
    public GameObject targetObject;
    public List<Transform> objectsList = new List<Transform>();

    private Transform targetTransform;

    private void Start()
    {
        targetTransform = targetObject != null ? targetObject.transform : transform;
        GetNestedChildren(targetTransform, depthLevel);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (depthLevel != objectsList.Count - 1)
        {
            objectsList.Clear();
            GetNestedChildren(targetTransform, depthLevel);
        }
    }

    private void GetNestedChildren(Transform parent, int depth)
    {
        if (depth <= 0)
        {
            objectsList.Add(parent);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.childCount; i++)
        {
            Transform child = parent.GetChild(i);
            objectsList.Add(child);
            GetNestedChildren(child, depth - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the objectsList variable and use it in this script as waypoints:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] waypoints;
    public float movementSpeed = 2f;
    public float minDistance = 1f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public float minHeight = 0f;
    public float maxHeight = 10f;
    public bool randomizeVisitOrder = false;
    public ObjectList objectList;

    private int currentWaypointIndex = 0;
    private bool isMoving = false;

    private void Start()
    {

        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Waypoint").GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        if (waypoints.Length > 0)
        {
            transform.position = waypoints[0].position;
        }

        StartMovement();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            MoveToWaypoint();
        }
    }

    private void MoveToWaypoint()
    {
        if (currentWaypointIndex >= waypoints.Length)
        {
            // Reached the last waypoint, stop moving
            isMoving = false;
            return;
        }

        Vector3 targetPosition = waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].position;
        targetPosition += RandomOffset();

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);

        // Check if we are close enough to the current waypoint
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) < minDistance)
        {
            currentWaypointIndex++;

            if (randomizeVisitOrder && currentWaypointIndex < waypoints.Length)
            {
                // Randomize the next waypoint index
                int randomIndex = Random.Range(currentWaypointIndex, waypoints.Length);
                Transform temp = waypoints[currentWaypointIndex];
                waypoints[currentWaypointIndex] = waypoints[randomIndex];
                waypoints[randomIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartMovement()
    {
        if (waypoints.Length > 0)
        {
            currentWaypointIndex = 0;
            isMoving = true;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 RandomOffset()
    {
        float distance = Random.Range(minDistance, maxDistance);
        float angle = Random.Range(0f, 360f);
        float height = Random.Range(minHeight, maxHeight);

        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(distance * Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), height, distance * Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        return offset;
    }
}
```

The problem is in the Start of the FlyCamera script:

```
 waypoints = objectList.objectsList;
```

objectsList is still null.  how can I wait first the objectsList to be get all objects first and then using it in the FlyCamera script?

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about your FlyCamera and if other scripts are as well waiting for it to be done? Should FlyCamera wait oncefor it to be done? Can ObjectList be done more than once? (Since it adjusts the items in Update(), else there would not be a need to have it in update)

Comment: @Zibelas I updated my question with the full code of the FlyCamera.  the objectsList can be done more then once when changing the Range but the idea is to use the objectsList as waypoints in the FlyCamera.  the FlyCamera is just a script that the camera fly between the waypoints.  for not there is no other scripts that use the FlyCamera or the ObjectList. the goal is when running the game that the camera will fly between the waypoints objectsList from ObjectList.

Comment: The easiest would be to have no code that is relevant in Start of your FlyCamera. Instead you could call directly StartMovement from ObjectList or trigger it over UnityEvents. I would add another ResetMethod to FlyCamera that handles what happens when you change ObjectList items later. I would use Events in case more scripts are in need of ObjectList and direct calls if FlyCam is the only consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that uses UnityEvents. You might want to add a second one to trigger something else in case you play around with `depthLevel`. You probably can as well remove the Update method in ObjectList and replace the code in a setter for depthLevel. That way you don't need to check every Update for it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class ObjectList: MonoBehaviour {

    [Range(0, 10)]
    public int depthLevel = 0;
    public GameObject targetObject;
    public List<Transform> objectsList = new List<Transform>();

    private Transform targetTransform;
    public UnityEvent onCalculationDone;

    private void Start() {
        targetTransform = targetObject != null ? targetObject.transform : transform;
        CalculateObjectList();
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (depthLevel != objectsList.Count - 1) {
            CalculateObjectList();
        }
    }

    private void GetNestedChildren(Transform parent, int depth) {
        //...
    }

    private void CalculateObjectList() {
        objectsList.Clear();
        GetNestedChildren(targetTransform, depthLevel);
        onCalculationDone?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Im not sure why you would acces the ChildrenTransforms in ObjectList when you have done the calculation on the objectList. But since the question is about how to react when the calculation is done, the code focused on that.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyCamera: MonoBehaviour {

    private ObjectList _objectList;
    private void Start() {
        _objectList = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Waypoint").GetComponent<ObjectList>();
        _objectList.onCalculationDone.AddListener(StartMovement);
    }

    private void StartMovement() {
        if (_objectList.objectsList.Count > 0) {
            //you can use the positions as well directly from objectList here
            //or you can copy them over to the old waypoints 
            transform.position = _objectList.objectsList[0].position;
            currentWaypointIndex = 0;
            isMoving = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean why I'm doing this Transform child = parent.GetChild(i); in the ObjectList ?

Comment: No, I mean why you do `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Waypoint").GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();` in FlyCamera`

Comment: you right ,  the reason i did it was because i couldn't do it with the ObjectList before you answered so I manually gave to some objects the tag "Waypoint" in the editor and then tried to use on it with the FlyCamera.  I know I messed it but it was for testing since it didn't work for me with the ObjectList.  and even though the FlyCamera is not a good script it's not moving the camera that good.  but the main goal and logic was to filter objects with the ObjectList and use this objects as waypoints.